# why getchar() doesn't get next value from input?

Tags: c

I have two dinamicaly created arrays:

```
int *sifre = malloc(brkomp* sizeof(int));
int *faktori = malloc(brkomp * sizeof(int));
```

and next part of code:

```
do {        
    int i = 0;

    while ((podatak[i] = getchar()) != ' ') 
    {
        i++;
    }
    sifre[j] = atoi(podatak);

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        podatak[i] = ' ';
    }

    i = 0;
    while ((end = podatak[i] = getchar()) != ' ' && end != '\n') 
    {
        i++;
    }
    faktori[k] = atoi(podatak);

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        podatak[i] = ' ';
    }
    j++;
    k++;
} while (end != '\n');
```

Input at console is like this:

```
23 2 257 1
```

When I debug after first iteration values of `sifre[j]` and `faktori[k]` are 23 and 2 respectively.
But after second iteration values are still the same. I expect 257 and 1.

Why this doesn't work?

Comment: Your code is **very** unreadable. Start with proper indent, it might even help you

Comment: Every line of code is enough for itself. There are no multyple-line unities.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to spend extra time on reparse your code in my head, and I'm sure I'm not the only one in that case here. Thanks for re-indent ;)

Comment: your code works for me. At what point in the code do you examine `sifre[j]` and `faktori[k]`?

Comment: The code seems to be correct, one side comment: one possible point of problem is the missing `podatak[i] = '\0'` at the end of every parse loop instead of "feel with spaces", because that configures a proper C string. In any case, I don't think any implementation of `atoi()` would continue parsing upon a `' '` (whitespace) and that's why your "feel with spaces" loop solution would suffice IMHO.

Comment: I put break point at line before j++ and k++. Then I start program and input numbers 23 2 257 1. Then press enter and program stops. Values for j and k are 0. Values in sifre[j] and faktori[k] are 23 and 2. Then I press "continue". Now j and k are 1. But values for sifre[j] and faktori[k] are still 23 and 2. I expect to be 257 and 1.

Comment: I made change and put '\0' at the end of char podatak[100]after every filling with ' '. That doesn't change situation. I checked value of podatak. It is the same in the second iteration as in the first. Something there is not good.

Comment: Can you express in a sentence or two what your objective is with this code?  i.e. are you simply trying to split the input into the two arrays without including the spaces?

Comment: I put four values in two arrays 23 in first array, then 2 in the second, then 257 in first and 1 in the second.

Comment: Are you sure you don't read sifre[0] & faktori[0] when the second stop occur ? because you have fill sifre[1] & faktori[1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with gcc 4.9.3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
     int i, j, k, end;
     char podatak[100];

     int *sifre = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
     int *faktori = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));

     j = k = 0;
     do {
          for (i = 0; (podatak[i] = getchar()) != ' '; ++i)
               ;

          podatak[i] = '\0';
          sifre[j++] = atoi(podatak);

          for (i = 0; (end = podatak[i] = getchar()) != ' ' && end != '\n'; ++i)
               ;

          podatak[i] = '\0';
          faktori[k++] = atoi(podatak);
     }
     while (end != '\n');
}
```

Comment: Yes. When I print field of the array good value is inside. This was misunderstanding of intelisense in Visual Studio 2013. When I debug in second iteration it shows {23} as in the first. It simply doesn't show correct value for arrayname[1]. It shows same as for arrayname[0]. Thanks everyone.